# How to add a custom field into template.php using Zen sub theme

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

First time poster here, I'm a designer not skilled at all with php and I have a small issue I don't seem to be able to solve. I'm making a site in drupal 7 using a sub theme on zen.
Btw this is a great CMS, even though people say it's really more a developers CMS. I have no trouble to do what I need using views, rules, display suite etc. So a big thank you for all the developers out there making this such a good CMS. But for this apparently simple problem... no module will help me (I think) and I'm kinda stuck.

So here it is: I'd like to add a subtitle next to the title in all my pages.

So what I did was to add a custom field into the content type basic page (machine name: field_sub_title) which is a simple text field.

I uncommented the following line in my template.php

`function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['sub_title'] = t('field_sub_title');
}`

Now my question is how do I load the content of my custom field into that variable?
I know i need to change the second part, but I don't have a clue as into what I need to change this.

Displaying the variable into the the page.tpl.php is something I know about so I only need help with the first part.

{EDIT}
Ok I found how to do this :)

I was looking for a solution in the wrong place. I don't need to change any thing in the template.php file.

Just needed to add this bit of code into my page.tpl.php:

```
<?php
print $node->field_sub_title['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

So I'm posting this here for other Drupal newbies struggling with this....

Answer (score 0):

Your solution may work for now, but there may be a more Drupal-y way to handle a problem like this. If you haven't noticed any problems yet, you may find one or more of the following issues down the road:

- Someone who doesn't know php or Drupal theming may need to change the way this works.
- If you're like me, you may forget where exactly in code this was implemented.
- You may see superfluous markup and/or errors on nodes (content) that do not have this sub-title field (ie. event content not having a sub-title field while basic pages and news articles do).

When you add a field to a content type, it will automatically appear anytime content in that content type is displayed. You should be able to add the sub-title field for your page, event or whatever else you need and have it automatically appear in the markup.

[image: Manage display of a content type]

You can 'manage display' of a content type to drag and drop the order for fields to appear. You could take it a step further by using a module like [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) to add formatting or layout per-content type.

---

If you feel like this isn't good enough and the markup for the subtitle must be at the same level as the page title (which is rare), at least add an if statement to make your code check to see if the variable is present before trying to print it. I'd also add a new variable and comments for code readability.

```
<?php
  $subtitle = $node->field_sub_title['und'][0]['value'];
  if($subtitle){
     print $subtitle;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using field_get_items or field_view_value, or at least use the LANGUAGE_NONE constant instead of 'und'
See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7 and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7

This has the added benefit of reducing the number of potential security holes you create.